# Hassio REST switch

Tags: rest, raspberry-pi, home-assistant

I'm trying to make Home Assistant button/switch, which changes state of my lamp through REST call.

I got set up server with command, which changes state of lamp on `192.168.43.21/lampSwitch` and returns json `{"state": "ON"}` or `OFF`, based on after-switching state.

I'm facing problem with scripting entities and showing current/returned state in Hassio - acquiring state and changing it via home-screen switch.

## My configuration:

```yaml
# Loads default set of integrations. Do not remove.
default_config:

# Text to speech
tts:
  - platform: google_translate

automation: !include automations.yaml
script: !include scripts.yaml
scene: !include scenes.yaml
rest:
  - scan_interval: 5
    resource: http://192.168.43.21/
    sensor:
      - name: "Temperatura"
        # unique_id: "sensor.temperature_sensor"
        json_attributes_path: "$.response.system"
        value_template: "{{value_json['temperature']}}"
        json_attributes:
          - "temperature"
      - name: "Wilgotność powietrza"
        # unique_id: "sensor.humidity_sensor"
        json_attributes_path: "$.response.system"
        value_template: "{{value_json['humidity']}}"
        json_attributes:
          - "humidity"
      - name: "Poziom wody"
        # unique_id: "sensor.water_sensor"
        json_attributes_path: "$.response.system"
        value_template: "{{value_json['water']}}"
        json_attributes:
          - "water"
lamp_switch:
  - command: "Lamp switch"
    trigger:
      platform: 
    action:
      url: http://192.168.43.21/lampSwitch/
```

I saw solution which uses cURL and command line, but I couldn't find any suiting example.
Note that the `rest` entities works just fine (shows up at home screen).
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I use this to launch applications on my Samsung TV. I define my_command in Configuration.yaml, then use:

```
/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/curl -X POST 'http://<<My_IP>>:8001/api/v2/applications/'{{ variables.my_command }}"
```

I call this from a button and pass a variable that defines the application that I want.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, that's not exactly the thing I wanted to implement, but it might help people checking this thread in future.

Have a nice day!